# MySQL query missing records in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I'm using the MySql.Data dll from MySql and trying to execute a query to transfer data from a MySQL table to an MSSQL table. I am running the following code:

```
MySqlCommand catCmd = new MySqlCommand();

catCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
catCmd.Connection = connection;

//Add categories to static class
catCmd.CommandText = "SELECT c.categories_id, categories_image, parent_id, categories_status, categories_name, categories_description FROM categories c JOIN categories_description d ON c.categories_id = d.categories_id ORDER BY categories_status";
MySqlDataReader catReader = catCmd.ExecuteReader();
while (catReader.Read())
{
    try
    {
        tables.categories.Add(new category(0, catReader.GetInt32(0), catReader.GetString(1), catReader.GetInt32(2), catReader.GetInt32(3), catReader.GetString(4), catReader.GetString(5)));
    }
    catch
    {
        tables.categories.Add(new category(0, catReader.GetInt32(0), "", catReader.GetInt32(2), catReader.GetInt32(3), catReader.GetString(4), catReader.GetString(5)));
    }
}
reader.Close();
```

When I run this query directly in MySQL query browser on the same DB it returns 115 records. But within the program, with the code above. It returns 106 rows. Theres nothing diffrent and i'm very frustrated. Any clues?

UPDATE

This is how i'm testing for the number of returned records:

[image: Visual Studio - Debug Results View]

Here is the same query in Mysql Query Browser

[image]

Comment: your code seem really strange... your `catch` block still acesses the `catReader` etc. ?

Comment: did the `catch` statement inserted successfully ?

Comment: That bit isn't the part that's not working. Basically, the category constructor will throw an error is the categories_image field is null. So instead it adds with a blank sting for this field. When debugging, hovering over 'catReader' shows 106 records which is incorrect. C&Ping that SQL query into query browser gives 115.

Comment: The inserts work fine. The while part of the code only happens 106 times since the resultset within catReader has 106 records.

Comment: Try putting a `counter` inside the `while`.. and print it finally

Comment: It is the MySqlDataReader (catReader) that has 106 records. The code within the try..catch is irrelevent.

Comment: This is just a dumb guess - I have no expertise with MySql, but I see that the JOIN is not sepcified as INNER, OUTER, LEFT, etc.  Could it be that the MySqlQuery browser is assuming an OUTER JOIN, but the .NET Framework treats this as an INNER join and alters the query accordingly?

Comment: It's a 1 to 1 relationship, It was originally a left join with the same results. I've tried fiddling with the query to see if it's a bug like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try Some thing Link this.

```
  public DataTable DataReader(string query)
    {
        DataTable mysqlDataTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            ConnectToMysql();// Add Mysql Connection Here. 
            MySqlDataAdapter readerAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, MysqlDBConnection);//MySqlConnection MysqlDBConnection;
            readerAdapter.Fill(mysqlDataTable);
            readerAdapter.Dispose();
            MysqlDBConnection.Close();
            MysqlDBConnection.Dispose();
            return mysqlDataTable;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: your catch like this is useless, at least log the exception or remove the catch block completely :)